# Listing all used IDs that contain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically list out all unique user IDs that contain the word "Error" in another tab without using Control+Shift+Enter or having to drag down the formula. Below is an example of what I mean:

| User ID | Error? |
| --- | --- |
| 351205 | Error |
| 345592 |  |
| 345590 | Error |
| 659582 | Error |

In another tab, I need a formula that will list the User IDs (which above are in column A) that have a "Error" written next to them (in column B)

So far, I've managed to find:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet 1'!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW('Sheet 1'!$B:$B)/('Sheet 1'!B:B="Error"),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

which works, but I still need to drag down the formula in order to list out all user IDs that have  "Error". Let me know if you need more clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: Only if you have Office 365, where you can use FILTER()

Comment: If you have Excel 2019 then you should be able to use `TEXTJOIN` to form your list in a single cell, i.e. `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet 1'!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW('Sheet 1'!$B:$B)/('Sheet 1'!B:B="Error"),ROW(1:5))),""))`

Comment: @SpectralInstance I looked at your formula and saw the ROW(1:5) and it worked just using my formula but editing that part from 1:1 to the 1:5. However, I need the formula to automatically detect the number of rows that have errors in them. Is there a way to edit the ROW function to be more dynamic?

Comment: @OscarV you can change it to `ROW(1:50)` or `ROW(1:500)` and it would still work (but will obviously take longer to calculate), i.e. that 400+ rows might be blank doesn't affect the result

Comment: @OscarV back to Scott's first comment.  What version of Excel are you using?  If you are using Excel 2021 or Excel O365, the solution here is an *entirely* different and much simpler approach.

Comment: @MaxR I have Office 365

Answer (score 0):

Office 365, and it’s robust use of array features, is a game changer that enables this to be accomplished in one function, in one cell.  Let’s assume that list of UserIDs are in A2:A50, and your “Error” flag column is in B2:B50.  Simply typing this into another cell somewhere else will automatically create what you are looking for:

`=FILTER(A2:A50, B2:B50 = “Error”)`

If you have cases where there are potentially duplicate IDs in column A, and you want only one of each UserID, Excel O365 also provides a UNIQUE() function that does the de-duplication for you:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A50, B2:B50 = “Error”))`

Also, the function can be placed on a different sheet, keeping your results separate from your data.  (I would usually recommend this):

`=FILTER(sheetl!A2:A50, sheet1!B2:B50 = “Error”)`

One last note:  I deliberately use a range like A2:A50 rather than A:A.  Having the filter function churn through millions of cells can be an unnecessary performance burden.  Filter eliminates the need to know the exact number of rows, but it’s still best to confine your workload to some area of the sheet.  For instance, if you anticipate the table will grow over time from 25 up to 150 rows, you can just use A2:A500 and likely never run off the end of your data.

Your use case really provides the perfect illustration for how dynamic arrays have profoundly transformed Excel.  It is really the most significant evolution of Excel in its history, it is a complete re-thinking of the Excel computational model.  If you are new to dynamic arrays, I’d recommend watching some YouTube video on the notion of arrays “spilling”.